# Getting nil after setting a value in Swift struct

Tags: swift

I'm not sure but after setting a value in struct I'm getting nil when trying to read the variable:

```
struct MainStruct : Decodable{
    var array : [InternalArray]?
}

struct InternalArray : Decodable{
    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?
    var Number : Int?
}



var testing: MainStruct?

testing?.array![0].firstName = "TEST"

print("test value \(testing?.array![0].firstName!)")
```

prints **nil**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, it seems like some entry-level exercise, but it seems to me like you are missing some key knowledge. I would suggest grabbing Apple's e-book on Swift and start from chapter one.

Comment: `InternalArray` ... isn't an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
var testing: MainStruct? = MainStruct()
testing?.array = []
testing?.array!.append(InternalArray())
testing?.array![0].firstName = "TEST"
```

Comment: of course, `testing` should not be optional any more.

Comment: Better yet: `var testing = MainStruct()`. And then remove all of the `?`.

Comment: @MikeT Of course your are free to accept any answer you wish but the answer by vadian is so much more helpful. That answer fully explains what all of your issues are and shows a much better way to fix them all. Please give that answer a serious review.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried vadian answer and it's not working I guess the problem that this answer also has testing?.array = []

Comment: But vadian answer properly initializes `array` right inside `MainStruct`. No need to do it manually every time.

Comment: I'm not sure why but if I try to set another array element [1] I get Index out of Range error

Comment: @MikeT That’s because the array doesn’t have 1st element

Answer (score 6):

First of all you are using too many optionals.

Three(!) issues:

1. `Testing` is not initialized.
2. `InternalArray` is not initialized.
3. You cannot access an array with index subscription if there is no item at given index (causes an exception).

---

```
struct MainStruct : Decodable {
    var array = [InternalArray]()
}

struct InternalArray : Decodable {
    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?
    var Number : Int?
}

var testing = MainStruct()
testing.array.append(InternalArray())
testing.array[0].firstName = "TEST"

print("test value \(testing.array[0].firstName!)")
```

Comment: Personally I would create and initialize the `InternalArray` instance and then add it to the array. It's kind of strange to append the empty `InternalArray` and then set the name indirectly.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't initialised testing.

Comment: And then once that is fixed the code will crash for force-unwrapping `array`. And once that is fixed, the code will crash for accessing the non-existing element at index 0.

Comment: @rmaddy: It's the "initial" reason for the error I'd imagine. I could be wrong though in thinking it shouldn't be up to someone to fix the OP's entire script!